# Julia: Defining promote_rule with multiple parametric types

Tags: julia

Say I want to define a `promote_rule()` for a type that has multiple parametric types, for example for type `MyType`:

```
abstract type State end
struct Open<:State end
struct Closed<:State end

struct MyType{T,S<:State}
    x::T
    state::S
end
```

Is there a way to define a `promote_rule()` which only promotes the first type and not the second, for example:

```
myFloat = MyType(1.0, Open()) # MyType{Float64, Open}
myInt = MyType(2, Closed()) # MyType{Int64, Closed}
promote(myFloat, myInt)
# (MyType{Float64, Open}, MyType{Float64, Closed})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the result of a promotion is *one common type*.  So while you can just recursively promote  the `T`s, you have to resort to a common supertype for the `S`s if you want to keep them as is.  Simply using `State` would be a valid choice, but a `Union` leads to a bit more fine-grained results:

```
julia> Base.promote_rule(::Type{MyType{T1, S1}}, ::Type{MyType{T2, S2}}) where {T1, T2, S1, S2} = MyType{promote_type(T1, T2), <:Union{S1, S2}}

julia> promote_type(MyType{Int, Closed}, MyType{Float64, Closed})
MyType{Float64,#s12} where #s12<:Closed

julia> promote_type(MyType{Int, Closed}, MyType{Float64, Open})
MyType{Float64,#s12} where #s12<:Union{Closed, Open}
```

You still have to define the respective `convert` methods for `promote` to work, of course; specifically, one ignoring the state type:

```
julia> Base.convert(::Type{<:MyType{T}}, m::MyType) where {T} = MyType(convert(T, m.x), m.state)

julia> promote(myFloat, myInt)
(MyType{Float64,Open}(1.0, Open()), MyType{Float64,Closed}(2.0, Closed()))
```

But be sure to test all kinds of combinations really well.  Promotion and conversion is really fiddly and hard to get right the first time, in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for this exactly what I was looking for. I'm a little confused though as to why the we need to subtype `MyType` in the convert function. In the definition of `MyType`, `S` is a subtype of `State`, and `Union{Closed, Open}` is also a subtype of `State`, so `Type{MyType{T}}==Type{MyType{T, S<:State}}` should include the case where `S` is `Union{Closed,Open}`? Apologies if this is answered somewhere in the doc, still quite new to the type system.

Comment: `Type`, like every other type constructor, is [invariant](https://docs.julialang.or/en/v1/manual/types/#Parametric-Composite-Types-1). So that equality, counterintuitively, does not hold. Your argument is completely logical, but this was a design choice.